# Microphone NOT working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Today I decided I will install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside my Windows 10 in a dual-boot system. After installing everything, I decided to install Discord to talk with some friends, then I noticed that my mic wasn't working. I thought that there may be a problem with my Discord install, but there isn't after I checked that my mic wasn't working in many more programs (including System Settings > Sound where no sound was showing up).

I also have to mention that my sound is working completetly fine. It's just the mic that's not working. Microphone is part of my headset (CREATIVE Sound BlasterX H7).

I checked all the forums and tried many different solutions. Some of them were:

- checking that the microphone isn't muted (it isn't);
- checking my settings in the pavucontrol panel. Trying to split the channels and lowering each channel at a time to check if the mic will work after that;
- looking at the Configuration panel in pavucontrol and setting it to Analog Stereo Duplex
- looking at the alsamixer and checking that the mic isn't muted (look at the pictures below) [I may have overlooked this step]
- trying to install a new vivid alsa dkms driver
- restarting the audio drivers

I am 100% sure my microphone is functioning, since I can use it without any problems on Windows 10 or on any other machine.

---

Imporant specs [since there may be a problem with my computer's drivers]:

i7-6700k Skylake / z170x gaming 7 Gigabyte / 2 monitors each having its own speakers

---

#### You can find all the images [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtIqg.jpg)

---

And here you can see all the audio devices:

```
➜  ~ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Option 3 worked. All I had to do was picking a profile with both 'Input and output'

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and tried everything you said. Finally, from alsamixer I changed the Channel option which was 6ch, to 4ch or 2ch, and the mic started capturing input, don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 worked.

> looking at the Configuration panel in pavucontrol and setting it to Analog Stereo Duplex

All I had to do was picking a profile with both 'Input and output'